# Inverse of the D’Alembert wave operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Let $f(x)$ a solution of the wave equation $\square f(x) = 0$. I don't understand why the following operator
$$
 \mathcal{D} \equiv \frac{1}{2}(\nabla^2)^{-1} (x_0\partial_0 - C)
$$
for arbitrary constant C, works as an inverse of the D'Alembert wave operator, namely:
$$
 \square \mathcal{D} \ast f(x) = f(x)
$$

Comment: What is $x_0$, is it the time coordinate? I assume $\partial_0$ is a time derivative? And what have you tried?

Comment: Yes $x_0$ is the time coordinate, $\partial_0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$ , $\square = \partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}=(\partial_0)^2 - \nabla^2$ and $f(x)$ is a function on Minkowski space-time. I tried as in Poisson equation $\nabla^2 \phi(\vec{x})=4\pi\rho(\vec{x})$ where $\phi(\vec{x})=(\nabla^2)^{-1}\ast \rho(\vec{x}) = \int d\vec{y}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|}\rho(\vec{y})$. ( $\ast$ stands for the convolution product).